# Killing OpenCL Kernels

Tags: kernel, opencl, infinite-loop, kill

Is there any way to kill a running OpenCL kernel through the OpenCL API? I haven't found anything in the spec.

The only solutions I could come up with are 1) periodically checking a flag in the kernel that the host writes to when it wants the kernel to stop, or 2) running the kernel in a separate process and killing the entire process. I don't think either of those are very elegant solutions, and I'm not sure #1 would even work reliably.

Comment: I'm not sure the second option is so good either.  The kernels still runs on the GPU even if you kill the process.  I was trying to do something similar in my ray tracer.  I checked keyboard in separate thread than the kernel.  If the user pressed 'ESCAPE' I wanted it the program to end immediately.  Last I looked at it I was getting a core dump when the programmed end.

Comment: I completely agree, they're both bad options. I'm hoping there's a better or more standard option out there.

Comment: pull out the plug, seriously you better split the kernel into well defined (and short time) computation parts and leave control decision to host side. for example nvidia driver kills your kernel if it doesnt finish in a couple of seconds and your gpu is connected to a display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the OpenCL API doesn't allow to interrupt a running kernel.  On some systems, a kernel running for more than a few seconds will be killed by the driver.

Ref. for Windows: [Timeout Detection and Recovery of GPUs through WDDM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570087(v=vs.85).aspx), and for Linux+NVidia: [Using CUDA and X](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x).

Nothing in the standard guarantees your option 1 will work. It almost certainly won't.
Your option 2 will work, but then you will have to communicate with the other process.

Splitting the kernel in smaller kernels, as suggested in the comments, is probably the best option.